# erro no método atualizar flutter + firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Boa tarde!

Estou com um erro nos itens `repo.senha` e `repo.nome`.

```
 void atualizar(Repositor repo) async {
    var update = Map<String, String>();
    update.putIfAbsent("senha", repo.senha);
    update.putIfAbsent("nome", repo.nome);
    await _userRef.child(repo.cpf).update(update).then((_) {
      print("Update Sucess");
    });
  }
```

a msg passa é:

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String Function()'

Comment: Por favor leia amigo: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1

Answer (score 1):

O erro esta em retornar um tipo `String`, coloque `.toString()` no final de cada objeto como nome e senha

Answer (score 0):

o Erro era o método recebe uma função que retorna um objeto do tipo String, tinha que passar ()=>repo.senha e ()=>repo.nome